# Query 'where' clause issue in Gemfire 9.3 Pulse

Tags: gemfire, geode, pulse

To start off, I am using the SecurityManager interface fyi. Now, I have just upgraded from Gemfire 9.1 to 9.3 and I noticed there's an issue with the querying. Before I could do a 'Select * from /Region where hostname="ABC" ' without any issue. Now when I query in 9.3 Pulse, it throws a "javalangException- Query could not be executed due to - org.apache.geode.security.NotAuthorizedException: Unauthorized access to method: getHostname".

In addition, under the @Override authorize method, I have given CLUSTER:WRITE,READ,MANAGE permissions for the user which I used to login to Pulse.

What could be the reason? It doesn't seems like Gemfire called for the @Override authorize method to check for rights.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior as of Geode 1.3.0. You can check [GEODE-3247](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-3247) for full details about the security reasons behind the change.

Either way, you can still go back to the previous behavior by starting your members with the system property `gemfire.QueryService.allowUntrustedMethodInvocation` configured as `true`. More details can be found in [Method Invocations](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/14/developing/query_select/the_where_clause.html#the_where_clause__section_D2F8D17B52B04895B672E2FCD675A676).

Hope this helps.
Cheers.

Comment: I see! Thank you.